# ¿Cómo detectar los valores no numéricos en una columna?

Tags: mysql, sql

Para detectar si el valor es no numérico puedo hacer:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE concat('', `columna` * 1) != `columna`
```

o

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE concat('', `columna` * 0) != 0;
```

Pero el problema es que eso no detecta valores con comas... mi tabla tiene este formato:

```
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|      id     |   columna   |  productos  |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|      1      |      5      |  producto1  |
|      2      |     3,5     |  producto2  |
|      3      |    158,8    |     ...     |
|      4      |    -56,0    |
|      5      |      14     |
|      6      |    -0,056   |
|-------------|-------------|
```

Lo primero que he hecho es reemplazar comas por puntos:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET `columna` = REPLACE(columna, ',', '.')
WHERE `columna` LIKE '%,%';
```

Entonces mi tabla queda:

```
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|      id     |   columna   |  productos  |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|      1      |      5      |  producto1  |
|      2      |     3.5     |  producto2  |
|      3      |    158.8    |     ...     |
|      4      |    -56.0    |
|      5      |      14     |
|      6      |    -0.056   |
|-------------|-------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esta expresión regular para detectar columnas cuyo contenido no sea un dígito:

```
select * from tabla where columna REGEXP '^-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+$'
```

o

```
select * from tabla where columna REGEXP '^-?\d*\,{0,1}\d+$'
```

si haces el cambio de puntos por comas.

Comment: Con eso no reconoce valores valores con coma ni siquiera los valores negativos...

Comment: Lo he modificado.

Comment: Antes tenía comas y las he puesto como puntos. He intentado con la primera expresión y me devuelve: `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)`

Comment: Si es con los datos que has puesto arriba (5; 3,5; 158,8; etc) cambiando la coma por punto (5; 3.5; 158.8; etc) es normal que no te devuelva resultados. Todos los valores de la columna "columna" cumplen la primera expresión regular.

Comment: Gracias !!!! Eres un crack ! Mi tabla tiene 580.000 registros, me parecía raro que ahora todos son numéricos, pero es verdad, lo son.